# get String from JSONArray

Tags: java, android

I have a JSONArray which store the content below:

```
[
"7d92a26dddcbd95c876479cf97afa404.jpg/500/500/0",
"2efb1955602498c0a82fd5c6f9611d0a.png/500/500/0",
"53633e49bc1a7725cf28cdbfbcd3f03b.jpg/500/500/0"
]
```

How do I get string inside the JSONArray? I try `jaImage.getString(0);` but `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception occur.

Below is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArrayStore.length(); i++)
{
    try 
    {
        JSONArray jaImage = jsonObjectStore[i].getJSONArray("images");
        if(jaImage == null)
        {
            Log.v("jaImage", "null");
        }
        else
            Log.v("jaImage", jaImage.toString());
        imgName[i] = new String[jaImage.length()];
        Bitmap sto_image;

        for (int j = 0; j < jaImage.length(); j++) 
        {
            String image = jaImage.getString(j);
            Log.v("jaImage", image);
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.v("JSONArray jaImage Error", e.toString());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

 below is my logcat:

```
06-29 03:02:48.301  24594-24618/mobile.howddy.com.howddymobile V/jaImage﹕ ["7d92a26dddcbd95c876479cf97afa404.jpg\/500\/500\/0","2efb1955602498c0a82fd5c6f9611d0a.png\/500\/500\/0","53633e49bc1a7725cf28cdbfbcd3f03b.jpg\/500\/500\/0"]
06-29 03:02:48.301  24594-24618/mobile.howddy.com.howddymobile V/JSONArray jaImage Error﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 03:02:48.301  24594-24618/mobile.howddy.com.howddymobile V/jaImage﹕ ["29778c73baca5d56d5a42c510cc5ae2e.png\/500\/500\/0","a35493d3aa674000566bfc3ef1053fcb.jpg\/500\/500\/0","a5fce41943837ba92f01a0b47aeb1054.jpg\/500\/500\/0"]
06-29 03:02:48.301  24594-24618/mobile.howddy.com.howddymobile V/JSONArray jaImage Error﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 03:02:48.301  24594-24618/mobile.howddy.com.howddymobile V/jaImage﹕ ["e308cc58d082906d936a23eae4bc4708.jpg\/500\/500\/0","ab9ce8cadcc379582210d4b65bda9ef7.jpg\/500\/500\/0","867a82d768deff21dfcb9cd988a26d58.jpg\/500\/500\/0","72df45688fe4a70b6c0b1db2d2a2533e.jpg\/500\/500\/0"]
06-29 03:02:48.301  24594-24618/mobile.howddy.com.howddymobile V/JSONArray jaImage Error﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: The code that you've posted seems fine. Are you certain that the `NullPointerException` occurs on the `jaImage.getString(0)` line? When you only output an `Exception` with `toString()` you lose the traceback, which is very helpful for debugging.

Comment: so what I am suppose to do? @DanGetz

Comment: @AhYong, in your catch block use something like `Log.v("Tag", "JSONArray jaImage Error", e);` to print the stacktrace...

Comment: Thank you so much, now finally I found where is the exception occur, its on `imgName[i] = new String[jaImage.length()];` @AbishekManoharan

Comment: Is your `imgName` a 2 dimentional array??? And have you initialized it with something like `imgName = new String[jsonArrayStore.length()][];`